# C++ Soap Toolkits

Tags: c++, web-services, soap

I am looking for a SOAP toolkit which I can use with C++ language on Linux system.I have taken a look at AXIS2C and i find it poorly documented. gSoap unfortunately requires a license, so are there any others which are out there?

Comment: How much SOAP support do you need? WS-*?

Comment: The style of communication is going to be document based. I need to ablity to read/write XMLS. There is both synchronous and asynchronous communication. For most part the XML payloads are straight forward.

Comment: Also any other approaches to achive the same (consume web services) would be appreciated.. As of now i understand that only way out is via a toolkit....

Comment: Does it need to be platform independent? Or is an OS-specific one for your OS sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

The only SOAP toolkit that I've used for C++ is [QtSoap](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtsoap/) which is fairly low level, only supports SOAP 1.1, and is [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) specific.

[gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soaplicense.html) can be used commercially without a license inasmuch as you aren't using the `wsdl2h` binary and associated generated code.

There are a [number of others](http://www.soapclient.com/SourceCode.html) that you could investigate.

> Also any other approaches to achive the same (consume web services) would be appreciated.. As of now i understand that only way out is via a toolkit

Since most web services are "*just*" XML, you don't need much in the way of a supporting library if you're willing to work through some of the protocol requirements. If your needs are simple, this may be sufficient.

Another option is to use bindings to Java or .NET where plenty of supporting libraries are available.

Comment: Unfortunately i need something linux (Fedora) specific and no ties to Qt.

Comment: Since i need to integrate with an existing C++ system , this cuts down my options drastically... i'd have done it in java in a heartbeat......